# Reporting services font problem when using remote app

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, fonts, remote-desktop, remoteapp

I have an application that runs as a remote app on Windows Server 2008. The application has a print form and it is viewed on a report viewer 10 control.

For eg. We would use computer A and computer B to run the remote app on the server and print a document to a printer C. But depending on where you are logged in from (A or B) the font used in the report seems to change. (Font 'Arial Narrow', I also tried Segoe Condensed but same results)

If I run the app directly on the client machine (not as a remote app) and print then everything comes out alright.

I have installed the font on both A and B and have the latest windows remote client installed.

Is there any reason why this whould be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to an DPI calculation issue in Windows Server 2008. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/482312/ssrs-report-font-rendering-issue

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and this KB patch fixed it for me.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2768741

Other workarounds that worked were rebooting and logging into the remote machine with a 4:3 aspect ratio.

Comment: The fix doesn't work for Server 2008. Only R2 and upwards.

Comment: Just to clarify, does it render correctly if you reboot the server and remote in with a 4:3 aspect ratio? `mstsc /v:SERVERNAME /admin /w:1024 /h:768`

Comment: It doesn't always work. I think once all remote sessions close it reverts the original aspect ratio. In any case asking users to only use a 4:3 aspect ratio is not an acceptable work aroud. If you can't update to Windows Server R2 or above then you can PDF export and print it rather than uaing the inbuilt print function. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95750/High-fidelity-printing-through-the-SSRS-Report-Vie